# Removing ul li when under max-width but leave child contents intact

Tags: javascript, css, html-lists

I'm not sure this is possible with css but, maybe with js.

```
<ul id="removeme-ul"> <- remove
    <li id="removeme-li"> <- remove
        <p>Contents</p> <- keep
    </li> <- remove
</ul> <- remove


$("#removeme-ul").remove();
$("#removeme-li").remove();
```

When the max-width is below a certain amount I would like to remove the ul & li but, leave the p with it's contents intact, I have tried doing it using my very limited knowledge of js but, nothing happens. And of course if I use display:none it removes all child contents including the p.

**EDIT**
This might show what I'm trying to achieve a little better

```
<ul>
<li><p>Login</p>

<- would like the login form to move here & remove/hide ul, li when in mobile view ->

    <ul id="remove-ul">
        <li id="remove-li">
            <p>Login Form</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

**EDIT TWO**

Sorry guys, this might make it a little clearer

```
<ul>
<li><a id="login-url" href="./login">Login</a>

<- it does indeed get appended here ->

    <ul>
        <li>
            <span id="login-form">
                <form>Login Form</form>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Thanks for the replies guys, I have used append and it does indeed add the login form under the login but, I have no idea how to move it back.

```
var ww = document.body.clientWidth;

var adjustMenu = function() {

if (ww < 871) {

    $("#login-url").append($("#login-form"));


    });
}

else if (ww >= 871) {



    });
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `.remove()` use `.display = "none"`.
Same way you can use `.display = "block"` to show it again.

But, if you are using jQuery, it has predefined function `.hide()`.
Also, jQuery has `.show()` for showing and `.toggle()` for toggling, in case you need it.